# Incrementing a string by itself returning undefined

Tags: javascript, string, undefined

I am trying to print a simple stair pattern using asterisks.

```
for (i=0;i<7;i++) {
    var asterisk = "*" + asterisk;
    document.write(asterisk+"</br>");
}
```

Using this code returns the desired result, although "undefined is printed next to it.

```
*undefined
**undefined
***undefined
****undefined
*****undefined
******undefined
*******undefined
```

Why is this occurring? It appears to be caused by the addition of the variable to itself. I know this is possible with integers, although is there something different when using strings? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before your loop starts, the `asterisk` variable contains the `undefined` value.

Add this statement before the loop:

```
var asterisk = '';
```

And then remove the `var` inside the loop. It won't hurt, but you don't need it. And don't forget to use a `var` on the `i` loop variable. (Thanks [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg) for the reminder!)

So you might end up with:

```
var asterisk = '';
for( var i = 0;  i < 7;  i++ ) {
    asterisk = "*" + asterisk;
    document.write( asterisk + "</br>" );
}
```

Comment: Declare counters too. :-) Consider: `for(var i=0, asterisk=''; i<7; i++)`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare asterisk outside of the loop and set it equal to an empty string.  You aren't setting asterisk to any value so it defaults to undefined.  That's why you are getting increments of "*undefined".  Also, declare i with the var keyword as well.

```
var asterisk = '';

for (var i=0; i<7; i++) {
    asterisk = "*" + asterisk;
    document.write(asterisk+"</br>");
}
```